# Syntax to get element in Javascript in Ionic Solution

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

When using the code on default HTML file and inline javascript on this page it is working.
But when I use the code in external javascript file (externalscript.js) in Ionic solution it throws error.
What is the correct syntax? Or is the problem that the inline script does not work the same as external script?

HTML

```
<table id="photosLayout">
 </table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#photosLayout").empty();
```

**Error message:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Clear (page.js:826)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (VM4935 original:1)
Clear @ page.js:826
onclick @ VM4935 original:1
```

Comment: `$` is the common usage of jQuery library; how do you load it? Since you are using Ionic4, you may also be using it with a framework (typically Angular, React or Vue); in that case, you may have more appropriate ways to do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I started new Ionic project with Angular. I don't understand how to solve this decoration issue. You mean I can install a jQuery module?

Comment: Hum you may be mixing many things... If your table is not handled by Angular / Ionic, you could just load jQuery and it should work fine. Otherwise, you are heading towards weird behaviour. You should follow Angular tutorials to learn how to achieve this with Angular instead of jQuery. If you need help, please make sure to provide enough details for people to be able to properly understand your environment.